# Where do I use my string to numerical function in my OrderBy function?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I built a sortable header for my table that works just fine. No errors, everything is linked up and working for the most part. There is one small issue that I knew before hand that would occur. My `data` JSON is string based with numerical values. They contain `%` and `$` before the numerical value, like so: $11  and/or 34%

Currently the headers are sortable, but they are not sorting the numerical intended values correctly. So I made this function below to transform and parse the strings into numerical values for the `comparator` used by my sortable headers function to actually sort the numerical values and not the strings themselves.

```
function numeric(x)
{
    if (x.includes('$'))
    {
        return parseFloat(x);
    }
    if (x.includes('%'))
    {
        return parseFloat(x);   
    }
    return x
}
```

I have one small problem, I do not know WHERE to use this function. Be it inside my component or inside the functions created used by my sortable header features, I just do not know.

Here is my table component, along with the functions created. The sortable header functionality is loosely based off of [Material UI documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#sorting-amp-selecting) for sorting rows.

```
function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
{
    if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]){
        return -1
    }
    if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]){
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}

function getComparator(order, orderBy)
{
    return order === "desc" 
        ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
        : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
}

const sortedRowInformation = (rowArray, comparator) =>
{
    const stabilizedRowArray = rowArray.map((el, index) => [el, index])
    stabilizedRowArray.sort((a, b) =>
    {
        const order = comparator(a[0], b[0])
        if (order !== 0) return order
        return a[1] - b[1]
    })
    return stabilizedRowArray.map((el) => el[0])
}

export default function TableContent(props)
{
    const [orderDirection, setOrderDirection] = useState('asc');
    const [valueToOrderBy, setValueToOrderBy] = useState('symbol');

    const { data } = props;
    
    const handleRequestSort = (event, property) =>
    {
        const isAscending = (valueToOrderBy === property && orderDirection === 'asc') 
        setValueToOrderBy(property)
        setOrderDirection(isAscending ? 'desc' : 'asc')
    }



    return (
        <>
            <TableContainer>
                <Table>
                    <QuickFactsHeader
                        data={data}
                        valueToOrderBy={valueToOrderBy}
                        orderDirection={orderDirection}
                        handleRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
                    />
                    {
                        sortedRowInformation(data, getComparator(orderDirection, valueToOrderBy))
                            .map((stock, index) => (
                            <TableRow key = {index} >
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.symbol}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.adj_close}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.change_percent}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.change}
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        ))
                    }
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </>
    );
}
```

Looking for some help here on where I should be using my `function numeric(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't even worry about your `numeric` function.

To get your `parseFloat()` to work properly, use `.replace(/(\$|%)/, '')` to replace all the `$` and `%` with `''` (an empty string). This basically will strip out all the dollar signs and percentages. It will only replace the first match, but shouldn't matter in your case.

Just update your `descendingComparator` to this:

```js
function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
{
    const numericA = parseFloat(a[orderBy].replace(/(\$|%)/, ''));
    const numericB = parseFloat(b[orderBy].replace(/(\$|%)/, ''));
    if (numericB < numericA){
        return -1
    }
    if (numericB > numericA){
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}
```

If you're worried about your data having numbers in it, you could also do `const numericA = parseFloat(a[orderBy].toString());`. I'm pretty sure that'll work without it, but `parseFloat` is meant to just accept strings, so you might want to include that.

Although you also said your data is coming from json, so I would recommend using parseFloat() anyway and you shouldn't need to add `toString()`.

Comment: Hey Brett, thank you for the help. I've tried using your snippet and your recommended `ToString`.Can you think of any reason why values with a % character can be ordered correctly, but values with a dollar sign character $, don't seem to be working?.

Comment: Yep, parseFloat won't work with a leading `$` I'll update my answer so that it works for you

Comment: Beautiful, it works great, thank you so much for sharing with me a simpler way to approach this.